# Sum with central trinomial coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, special-functions

I am trying to evaluate the following sum:
\begin{equation}
 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-ix)^n}{(n+2)!} T_n
\end{equation}

where $T_n$ represent the [central trinomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinomial_triangle) , with the following convetion: $T_0 = 1, T_1 =1, T_2 = 3, T_3 = 7 ...$. I know that this sum converges, however I do not know if there is a way to evaluate it. If it is not possible (or too hard) it would be nice if I could obtain at least the asymptotic behavior when $x \to \infty$ .

Comment: Where is this question from? Another user posted a question about central trinomial coefficients recently: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3965324/deriving-generating-function-for-centered-trinomial-coefficients/

Comment: Actually I stumbled upon this when I was doing some calculations in physics (for fun). They popped up when I expressed their generating function $\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1+x)(1-3x)}}$ in the series form. I would say that it is a coincidence that another user recently was doing something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the exponential generating function (see OEIS [A002426](https://oeis.org/A002426)) $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty T_n \frac{z^n}{n!}=e^z I_0(2z)$$ to obtain an integral representation for the sum. Here $I_0(x)$ is the zeroth modified Bessel function, but the substitution $z=-i x$ converts it to

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty T_n \frac{(-i x)^n}{n!}=e^{-i x} I_0(-2i x)=e^{-i x}J_0(2x)$$
where $J_0(x)$ is the regular zeroth Bessel function. Integrating both sides twice (with base point $0$) and dividing by $x^2$ produces

\begin{align}
 \sum_{n=0}^\infty T_n \frac{(-i x)^{n}}{(n+2)!}
&=\frac{1}{x^2}\int_0^x\int_0^{x''} e^{-i x''}J_0(2x'')\,dx''\,dx'\\
&=\frac{1}{x^2}\int_0^x (x-t)e^{-i t}J_0(2t)\,dt.
\end{align}
where in the second line I've made use of the [Cauchy formula for repeated integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_formula_for_repeated_integration). This is as far as I know how to go, unfortunately: Mathematica does not yield a closed form. But this may be sufficient for asymptotics or numerical exploration.

Comment: I'll confess that I don't rightly know how to derive this exponential g.f. As such, I've opened up another question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3966409/137524

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer! I posted an elementary derivation of the exponential generating function on your question.

Comment: There is a typo, the upper limit $x''$ should be $x'$.

Comment: If we write $J_0(x) = \int_0^\pi e^{i x \cos z} dz/\pi$, interchange the order of integration and then change the integration path for the remaining integral from $[0, \pi]$ to $\gamma = [0, \pi e^{-\pi i/4}/\sqrt 2, \pi]$, we get
$$S = -\frac 1 {\pi x^2} \int_\gamma \frac
 {e^{i x (2 \cos z - 1)} - i x (2 \cos z - 1) - 1}
 {(2 \cos z - 1)^2} dz =
\frac 1 {x \sqrt 3} - \frac i {3 x^2 \sqrt 3} + O(x^{-5/2})$$
(the non-exponential part can be integrated in closed form and $\gamma$ is a valid contour for the steepest descent method for the exponential part).

Comment: @Maxim Thanks for the answer, but I have one question. I'm not sure exactly how to use steepest descent method in this case. Shouldn't imaginary part of the exponent be constant along the path we choose? It seems that we can't choose such a path because of the end points.

Comment: @RedGiant Let $f(z) = i (2 \cos z - 1)$. We can combine the two paths $\Im f(z) = 1$ (going from $0$ to $\pi/2 -i \infty$) and $\Im f(z) = -3$ (going from $\pi/2 - i \infty$ to $\pi$), but it is not necessary. It suffices to take any path s.t. $\Re f(z) = 0$ at the endpoints and $\Re f(z) < 0$ everywhere else on the path. Then an arbitrarily small portion of the path (containing the endpoints) gives the full asymptotic expansion of the integral, even regardless of the direction of the path at the endpoints. We choose $e^{\pm \pi i/4}$ only to make the integral amenable to Laplace's method.